# Django Initial Value For Foreignkey Field

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

I'm trying to pass some initial data to the volume field in `CourseForm`, but for some reason it won't work. The volume field is a `ForeignKey` to a table in the database.

It doesn't give me errors; it just doesn't display any information.

My model with the respective volume field:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    volume = models.ForeignKey(CourseVolume)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    # ... code shortend to simplify
```

My `Modelform` with its model set to `Course`

```
class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view where I'm trying to set the initial data for the `CourseForm`. It just doesn't seem to work. `user.volume_preference` returns an integer from 1 to x which is the id for the specific volume.

```
def view_course_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CourseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('teaching_courses')
    else:
        user = MbsUser.get_user_from_ad(request.session['username'])
        if user.volume_preference is not None:
            volume = user.volume_preference
            form = CourseForm(initial={'volume': volume})
        else:
            form = CourseForm()
    return render(request, 'teaching/course_create.html', {'form': form})
```

My CourseVolume model:

```
class CourseVolume(CourseEnum):
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta(CourseEnum.Meta):
    db_table = 'mbs_course_volume'
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: you should mention initial values to the fields in `CourseVolume` model. Then it assigns to the `volume` field.

Comment: Try assigning the volume instance instead of the id: `volume = CourseVolume.objects.get(id=user.volume_preference)`

Comment: So It's the CourseVolume Model I need to change. I've added it to my post. But considering it uses `db_table =` it doesn't seem to allow something like: `self.fields[field_name].initial = field_value` 
I tried your method @Alasdair with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a default value for the volume field. The value should be the existing id of the related table(CourseVolume).

```
volume = models.ForeignKey(CourseVolume, default=1)
```

Comment: This works, but I wouldn't know how to update this value dynamically with `user.volume_preference`. The default is (can be) different for each user.